# Can you programatically hide tasks in outlook

Tags: vb.net, outlook, add-in

I'm looking to develop an outlook add-in to manage tasks. I would like outlook tasks to only be viewable within this add-in, and not visible in the regular task pane. Is this possible?

Comment: You are looking for this: **[Controlling Outlook region’s state and form’s size in Add-in Express 2010](http://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2010/06/25/outlook-regions-forms-size-state/)** Hope this helps.

Comment: Is this related to this question? http://stackoverflow.com/q/11637081/190829

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to try view filters. In Outlook 2010 they're at View -> View settings -> Filter -> Advanced. There are already two filters set by default. If you exploit them they might be useful so you can modify your task programmatically to make your tasks being filtered. I'm positive that you'll be able to set more filters programmatically. In order to hide tasks you could for example specify a filter for Categories -> contains -> 'hidden'.

Answer (score 0):

I have another suggestion, you can place your own .net form (system.windows.forms.form) over the list of tasks for all Outlook folders containing standard task items and display your own tasks in that form. Is it what you are looking for?

Best regards,
Dmitry Kostochko
Add-in Express Ltd.

Comment: Basically I want something to display a a custom task class, in the form of an add in. I just also need to make it so these custom tasks do not get displayed in the same place as std tasks are also displayed. Basically the only place they should be viewable is within the addin.